# The same content file, the MD5 value is different

Tags: hash, cryptography, md5, md5sum

As we know,the md5 of two different files(even if their contents are same) is different,just like this:

```
[langshiquan@cp01-rdqa-dev002.cp01.baidu.com md5test]$ ll
total 16
drwxrwxr-x  7 langshiquan langshiquan 4096 Mar 28 19:41 output
drwxrwxr-x  3 langshiquan langshiquan 4096 Mar 28 19:44 test
-rw-rw-r--  1 langshiquan langshiquan  100 Mar 28 19:54 test.sh
-rw-rw-r--  1 langshiquan langshiquan   69 Mar 28 19:48 test.sh~
[langshiquan@cp01-rdqa-dev002.cp01.baidu.com md5test]$ sh test.sh
[langshiquan@cp01-rdqa-dev002.cp01.baidu.com md5test]$ md5sum output.tar
2b7f05590cd4c8665dd61bbf745bbeee  output.tar
[langshiquan@cp01-rdqa-dev002.cp01.baidu.com md5test]$ sh test.sh
[langshiquan@cp01-rdqa-dev002.cp01.baidu.com md5test]$ ll
total 18212
drwxrwxr-x  7 langshiquan langshiquan     4096 Mar 28 19:41 output
-rw-rw-r--  1 langshiquan langshiquan 18606080 Mar 28 19:54 output.tar
drwxrwxr-x  3 langshiquan langshiquan     4096 Mar 28 19:44 test
-rw-rw-r--  1 langshiquan langshiquan      100 Mar 28 19:54 test.sh
-rw-rw-r--  1 langshiquan langshiquan       69 Mar 28 19:48 test.sh~
[langshiquan@cp01-rdqa-dev002.cp01.baidu.com md5test]$ md5sum output.tar
3601eff99bc78198b152b04ca94c53d0  output.tar
```

test.sh script shell :

```
#! bin/bash
cp -rp output ./test/
echo "1" > ./test/output/a.txt
tar -cf output.tar ./test/* -C ./
```

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.
Q1.So I think whether there is a hash function similar to MD5,(e.g.i call it just "HashStr") which makes the same "HashStr" for files with the same contents but different attributes.
Q2.Or when we can make TAR, how can we exclude the attributes of the file to make the same MD5?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Its unclear what you are asking, md5sum does *not* care about the name of the file, differently named files with the same content returns the same md5 - if you observe that behaviour the files you are comparing are different.

Comment: i know what you are saying,i just need a hash ,which can make that the same content files have the same hash.

Comment: md5sum does that, if the contents are the same the hash is the same?

Comment: Oh,md5sum can't make it.

Answer (score 2):

If the files are the same, then the hashes will be the same.  If the attributes (rather than the file contents) are different, then you need to add the attributes to the file before hashing.  Put the attributes you want to include into a piece of text and add it to the file.  Then hash attributes + file as a single piece of data.

Comment: Moreover, notice `tar` is not deterministic as at least some versions of `tar` will include the PID in the archive.  Thus, duplicate runs of tar will actually produce different files.

Comment: Thanks ，because "put the attributes you want to include into a piece of text and add it to the file" , i can't exclude the attributes of the file. right?